# How to find only "sharp peaks" of a signal in python?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am trying to detect level shifts in signals automatically by detecting peaks in the difference between two rolling windows.

I basically want to detect peaks which are "sharp" and don't have a wide plateau.

I want to detect the peaks in the following signals

[image]

But not the "wide" peak in the following image

[image]

I know of the functions such as `find_peaks` from scipy.signals but without specifying any parameter it also picks up the wide peaks in my signals.

So are there any of its parameters one should tune to only pick up "sharp" peaks? Or could I do some specific preprocessing step to the data first to make it easier to pick?

Appreciate any input!

Comment: I suggest you include some example data and mark what you want as peak and what you don't in your picture.

Comment: Just a quick comment, you may need to filter your purple curve in figure 1 before using scipy.signal.find_peaks. I like to use `scipy.signal.firwin` to design a sequence-domain FIR filter with 16 taps and a cutoff frequency between 0.15*Fs and 0.45*Fs. The nyquist limit is 0.5*Fs. You may also be able to get away with not filtering your data if you specify the `height` and `prominence` parameters correctly in `scipy.signal.find_peaks`

Answer (score 1):

The`scipy.signal.find_peaks` function accepts a `width` parameter. If the parameter is a tuple, then the first value in the tuple is the minimum width and the second value is the maximum width. (e.g. `width=(0,10)`). The width specification is with respect to the "sequence" axis (i.e., `list(range(len(data))`), not any other axis (for instance your date axis in your second example).

Another option is `scipy.signal.argrelextrema`. For the comparator, you can use np.greater. The minimum peak width will be controlled by the `order` parameter, where `min_width=order*2+1`. You can calculate the width of each peak by descending the slope on either side until the data begins to rise again. You can then loop through your peaks and filter based on width requirements.

Your best bet is probably `scipy.signal.find_peaks`.